# How to redirect (or Alias) jump page with Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, alias, mod-alias

I'm not an Apache expert but need to make a small change to a web server. We are introducing a "jump page" URL that is different from a primary URL (for tracking reasons).

```
/productA/index.html
/productA/jump_index.html
```

Basically i want to **log** that `jump_index.html` was requested and then return `index.html`. I don't want the client to wait 8 seconds or so for a redirect.

How should we be handling this? Simply symlink (or alias) the file in the filesystem? Use mod_alias `Alias Match` (if so how exactly)? something better still?

**Edit:** `mod_rewrite` in httpd.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Redirects don't actually take 8 seconds.  That delay you see on some pages is added *on purpose* so that you have time to read the message.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an HTTP redirect, e. g. with [RedirectPermanent](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectpermanent) or more dynamically with [RedirectMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch):

```
RedirectPermanent /productA/jump_index.html http://example.com/productA/index.html
RedirectMatch permanent \/(product.*)\/jump_index\.html http://example.com/$1/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a simple redirect header

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=index.html">
```

for example

Comment: there is a slight delay, of course, but nowhere near 8 seconds. you could use `mod_rewrite` for something much faster.

Comment: `RewriteEngine On` and `RewriteRule jump_index.html index.html` in `.htaccess` for example. i do not know if jump_index.html and index.html will show in your access.log, though, for tracking.

Comment: so rather than use .htaccess where would i put this RewriteRule in in httpd.conf (see above). Immediately before `</IfModule>` or before `RewriteRule .* - [F]` ? somewhere else entirely?

Comment: perhaps after it. i'm not an expert with mod_rewrite, sadly.